# Issue with InkWell/CachedNetworkImage inside stack

Tags: flutter

There is unexpected side effect while using InkWell in the following structure:

```
InkWell(
          onTap: ...,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              upper(...),
              lower(...),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Where `upper(...)` is

```
Expanded(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: ...,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              placeholder: (context, url) => const Loader(),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(...
```

The sideeffect is the following:

1. If CachedNetworkImage fails to load image, everything works as expected (click on card has proper ripple through the card)
2. If CachedNetworkImage successfully loads the image, ripple only happens for `lower` section of card

Any ideas how to make it work for whole card when image is loaded?